# Find index of first row closest to value in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe containing multiple columns. For each column, I would like to get the index of the first row that is nearly equal to a user specified number (e.g. within 0.05 of desired number). The dataframe looks kinda like this:

```
ix   col1   col2   col3
0    nan    0.2    1.04
1    0.98   nan    1.5
2    1.7    1.03   1.91
3    1.02   1.42   0.97
```

Say I want the first row that is nearly equal to 1.0, I would expect the result to be:

- index 1 for col1 (not index 3 even though they are mathematically equally close to 1.0)
- index 2 for col2
- index 0 for col3 (not index 3 even though 0.97 is closer to 1 than 1.04)

I've tried an approach that makes use of argsort():

```
df.iloc[(df.col1-1.0).abs().argsort()[:1]]
```

This would, according to other topics, give me the index of the row in col1 with the value closest to 1.0. However, it returns only a dataframe full of nans. I would also imagine this method does not give the first value close to 1 it encounters per column, but rather the value that is closest to 1.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you explain more point 3 ?

Comment: @jezrael The first result to fall within a 0.05 tolerance

Comment: @Dillon - Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) for difference, convert to absolute values by [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html), compare by [`lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) (`<`) and last get index of first value by [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
a = df.sub(1).abs().lt(0.05).idxmax()
print (a)
col1    1
col2    2
col3    0
dtype: int64
```

But for more general solution, working if failed boolean mask (no value is in tolerance) is appended new column filled by `True`s with name `NaN`:

```
print (df)
    col1  col2  col3
ix                  
0    NaN  0.20  1.07
1   0.98   NaN  1.50
2   1.70  1.03  1.91
3   1.02  1.42  0.87

s = pd.Series([True] * len(df.columns), index=df.columns, name=np.nan)
a = df.sub(1).abs().lt(0.05).append(s).idxmax()
print (a)
col1    1.0
col2    2.0
col3    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: does `lt` mean 'less than'?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, you have some tolerance value `tol` for the nearly
match threshold. You can create a mask dataframe for
values below the threshold and use [first_valid_index()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html#pandas.Series.first_valid_index)
on each column to get the index of first match occurence.

```
tol = 0.05
mask = df[(df - 1).abs() < tol]
for col in df:
    print(col, mask[col].first_valid_index())
```